# Very odd html/css

Tags: html, css

**Jfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/H5LmF/2/

If you look at this, my white bar is at top, which I already don't know why he is there, it's like he doesn't recognise my banner. Anyway I want my white bar to be beneath the banner at the center (red bar in the picture). I really don't know what to do anymore and see this as my last resort

html:

```
<div class="navCont">
    <div class="bancont"><img class="banner" src="images/banner.png"></div>
    <nav class="cssmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prijzen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Examen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Leerlingen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="midden">

    <div class="middentextvak">
    </div>
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
</div>
```

css:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('images/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}


.banner
{
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative; 
    float: left;

}


.cssmenu
{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background-color:black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;

}

.cssmenu ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 6%;
}

.cssmenu li
{
    display:inline; 
    padding-left: 5%;

}

.cssmenu li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:Eras Bold ITC;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.cssmenu li a:hover
{
    color: #0671ca;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:Eras Bold ITC;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.middentextvak
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;

}

.logo
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
    width:50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Ok uploaded the jfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be about the way you are floating elements.

Try

```
.midden {
 clear:both;
}
```

to tell the midden div to appear below any floated elements.

Comment: Ah thanks! but the white bar won't appear infront of the logo image, do you know how to do this? (middendiv infront of the logo)

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of float:left for the menu, the white box will go below the menu and in the center. The menu defaults to left, so getting rid of float:left didn't change anything else.
Broadly speaking, setting a float property for an element makes it doesn't affect the position of elements around it like it normally would.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that!